# Moodle Editing Templates

Tags: templates, moodle

How do I separate the blocks when editing a template?

Example:

```
<?php echo $ output->blocks('course_summary', 'cssCourse'); ?>
```

I want to use the block with the course summary id, but he does not appear on the first page ...

................................................................

Or else thought but can not develop further on is this:

```
<?php echo $output->login_info(); ?>
```

It prints the block login information, which gives to make loggof and edit profile, etc ... But I can about the other blocks, or disassemble the login info to separate for example Avatar User's his name ... etc...

Still waiting for help ...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Overriding_a_renderer

Basically you need to override output renderers to customize what $OUTPUT->blocks() renders. That method calls another method that will render blocks for a region (side-pre in this case). You should dig through the core_renderer class. Be careful when overriding blocks as to not break the editing state, which brings in extra controls to drag-and-drop and edit each block.

The block content itself is rendered in the block class. You can find it in moodle/blocks//block_.php. These you cannot override, but gives you an idea where the content comes from.

Related links that might be helpful:

- https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Output_renderers
- https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Renderer
- https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Output_API
- https://www.google.com

Comment: hi, I understand where it comes from the blocks but could not put them to work, u have any example to help me?

thanks

Comment: You will need to elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish.